# Internal server error after submitting a form with CSRF protection enabled in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3, internal-server-error, csrf-protection

I'm using Codeigniter 3.1.3 and having CSRF protection enabled in config file. Somehow I'm always getting 500 (Internal server error) from the ajax $.post if the form passes the validation. I'm not getting that error if the validation fails. Any thoughts?

Here is the csrf setting in codeigniter config file:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_token_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
```

Here is my login form within the view login.php:

```
<form id="login_form" class="col-12 col-md-8 mx-auto" method="post">

    <div class="alert" id="login-alert" role="alert"></div>


    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Username</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Password</span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="pwd" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" id="login_btn" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

I'm using AJAX $.post to submit the form

```
$("#login_btn").click(function(){
            var data = $("#login_form").serialize();
            var csrf_name = "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>";
            //get_cookie is a function that I defined to retrieve the cookie 
            var csrf_cookie = get_cookie("csrf_cookie_name");


            $.post('index.php/sentinel/verify_user',data+"&"+csrf_name+"="+csrf_cookie,function(data){
                if(data && data !== '')
                {
                    data = data.replace(/(<p>)/g,'').replace(/(<\/p>)/g,'<br>');
                    $("#login-alert").prop('class','alert alert-danger').html(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    //success
                    //redirect to the main page

                }


            });            
        });

function get_cookie( check_name ) {
    var a_all_cookies = document.cookie.split( ';' );
    var a_temp_cookie = '';
    var cookie_name = '';
    var cookie_value = '';
    var b_cookie_found = false; // set boolean t/f default f

    for ( i = 0; i < a_all_cookies.length; i++ )
    {
         // now we'll split apart each name=value pair
        a_temp_cookie = a_all_cookies[i].split( '=' );
        // and trim left/right whitespace while we're at it
        cookie_name = a_temp_cookie[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

        // if the extracted name matches passed check_name
       if ( cookie_name == check_name )
       {
            b_cookie_found = true;
           // we need to handle case where cookie has no value but exists (no = sign, that is):
            if ( a_temp_cookie.length > 1 )
            {
                cookie_value = unescape( a_temp_cookie[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') );
            }
           // note that in cases where cookie is initialized but no value, null is returned
           return cookie_value;
           break;
        }
        a_temp_cookie = null;
        cookie_name = '';
    }
    if ( !b_cookie_found )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function verify_user(){


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pwd', 'Password', 'required|callback_alpha_numeric_dots');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_numeric_dots','Invalid Password.');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pwd','Password','callback_login_check');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            echo validation_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            echo '';
        }

    }

}

public function login_check(){
    $data = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post());
    $rep_info= $this->sentinel_model->user_verify($data);
    if($rep_info === FALSE)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('login_check', 'Incorrect Username or Password');
        return FALSE;

    }
    else
    {
        //set session data here
        $newdata = array(
            'id' =>$this->encryption->encrypt($rep_info['user_id']),
            'name'  => $rep_info['user_name'],
            'email' => $rep_info['user_email'],
            'logged_in' => TRUE
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        return TRUE;

    }
}
public function alpha_numeric_dots($str)
{
    return (bool) preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9.]+$/i', $str);
}
```

I'd also like to redirect users to another view without changing the url after they logged in successfully. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: show your function `get_cookie`

Comment: Added function get_cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CSRF` token is added to the form as a hidden input when the `form_open()` function is used and its quick fix.

A cookie with the `CSRF` token's value is created by the `Security` class, and regenerated if necessary for each request.

If `$_POST` data exists, the cookie is automatically validated by the Input class. If the posted token does not match the cookie's value, `CI` will show an error and fail to process the `$_POST` data.

So basically, it's all automatic - all you have to do is enable it in your `$config['csrf_protection']` and use the `form_open()` function for your form.

**So client side you just have to post**

```
$.post('index.php/sentinel/verify_user',$("#login_form").serialize(),function(data){

});
```

**In your controller**

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

**and in you view file**

```
<?php echo form_open('sentinel/verify_user', 'id="login_form" class="col-12 col-md-8 mx-auto"'); ?>
    <div class="alert" id="login-alert" role="alert"></div>


    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Username</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Password</span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="pwd" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" id="login_btn" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

**OR**

create hidden input inside form like below

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>" />
```

**OR**

without modifying view file, (corrected version of what you have posted )

```
var data = $("#login_form").serialize();
$.post(
        'index.php/sentinel/verify_user',
        data+"&" + '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' +"="+ '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
        function(data){

 });
```

**For comment**

> Actually I just noticed that I'm getting 403(Fordidden) error instead
>   of 500 once i click the login button the 2nd time

From [the docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf):

> Tokens may be either regenerated on every submission (default) or kept the same throughout the life of the CSRF cookie. The default regeneration of tokens provides stricter security, but may result in usability concerns as other tokens become invalid (back/forward navigation, multiple tabs/windows, **asynchronous actions**, etc). You may alter this behavior by editing the following config parameter
>
> ```
> $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
> ```

Set that to FALSE.

Comment: I know form_open() automatically adds the hidden input field. And I've tried that. The serialized form data should already contains the csrf token. Why are you still appending it to the data variable? Anyways, with that method, I  start getting the 500 error once I click the submit button the 2nd time no matter if the form is valid or not

Comment: @Vaeianor: 3rd one is corrected version of your code, which will not contain csrf token when you serialize (`without using form_open or hidden input in view`)

Comment: Actually I just noticed that I'm getting 403(Fordidden) error instead of 500 once i click the login button the 2nd time

Comment: @Vaeianor: Yeah, codeigniter will warn forbidden, when csrf checking fails

Comment: Okay I was able to fix the 403 error by setting $config['csrf_regenerate'] to FALSE in codeigniter config file. However, I'm still getting the 500 error if the form passes validation

Comment: @Vaeianor: see update, `$config['csrf_regenerate'] =FALSE;`

Comment: @Vaeianor: With any one of the solutions given above, it should work, please check carefully, and read log

Comment: I think I know what might have caused the problem. I manually set some session data inside the login_check function in my controller. The 500 error is gone after I remove that piece of code. But why?

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. It was kinda stupid. The user data $rep_info returned from the model was an object. But I treated it as an array. Too bad that I wasn't able to see any errors regarding that besides the 500 error. Anyways thanks for your help @Akshay Hegde

Comment: Everything is working fine for me. but here i am facin different isue like. suppose i want to show different page rather than error_general.php....  how i will be able to achive this ?